# PendingIntent not being launched from Notification

Tags: android

I've tried about 20 different StackOverflow answers and NONE are working!

Just want to launch an activity from my notification I bring up. It's not working. It isn't doing anything, If I go to my home screen and click on it, it doesn't even bring up the application.

I've added a bunch of stuff since the beginning, so sorry for all the stuff that may not even be needed. I just keep looking through SO and trying solutions.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg, String cont, String title) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Log.d("msg",msg);

int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WalkerRequest.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
Log.d("Intent","setting content intent");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.paw_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(cont))
                .setContentText(cont);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Here is the full class, it's from google directly pretty much...

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: ", extras.toString(), "Nada");
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: ", extras.toString(), "nada");
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                String cont = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
                String title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");

                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: ", cont, title);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.

    private void sendNotification(String msg, String cont, String title) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Log.d("msg",msg);

        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WalkerRequest.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Log.d("Intent","setting content intent");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.paw_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(cont))
                        .setContentText(cont);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is the receive

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try instead of .getActivity(this, ..... try .getActivity(getBaseContext,.....

Comment: Yea I had that before as well, doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getApplicationContext()` will not be available when your application not in active state, so better to use `context` of that service.

What i would suggest is to trace back as far as possible through the methods to the place where the push notification intent gets received, and change whatever Context that gets passed down to the `onReceive()` method, and replace it with `getApplicationContext()` with `context` and then you can use the context parameter within the method.

Comment: Hey I unfortunately don't understand what you're saying, care to provide some sample code? Sorry!

Comment: I'm editing the post with the full code of the class

Comment: can you post you Service Code i will suggest you what to change

Comment: Added both the rest of that class and the receive class

Comment: Change this  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WalkerRequest.class); to  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, WalkerRequest.class);

Comment: Yea I had it like that originally. Still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Can you trace logs when you click on notification what it says in logcat.

Comment: What could I do to trace it? I get nothing happening currently in the logs when I do this(I've got them running over ADB on Android Studio)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66237/discussion-between-user1610719-and-rajareddy-polamreddy).

Answer (score -1):

try this:`public void createNotification() {
        try {
            Intent pnIntent = new Intent(this, newActivity.class);
            pnIntent.putExtra("notificationId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 01, pnIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.running));
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_permanent_notification);
            builder.setAutoCancel(false);
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.setPriority(1);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            final NotificationManager notificationManger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManger.notify(permanentNotificationId, notification);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnityApplication", "Error while creating notification", e);
        }
    }`

Comment: There are a bunch of errors with this...for example the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK has an error which basically says I can't use that option